# RLMException - object has been deleted when scrolling in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I delete 1 object realm in bd and success result but when scrolling in tableview to the position that before ocupated this object , app broken . Also delete the object in array and reload tableview I don't understand the problem because in my array there isn't reference to this object.
The message error is:

> RLMException: Object has been deleted or invalidated.

```
self.items.remove(indexPath.row)
presenter.deleteUser(user:items[indexPath.row])
tableview.deleteRows(at:[indexPath],with : .fade)
```

and code for delete in bd is:

```
func deleteUser(user:User){
  try! realm.write {
   realm.delete(user)
  }
}
```

All ok but when I do scrolling in tableview this wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem
First delete item to bd and after delete item to actual array , if not after element don't exist :

```
presenter.deleteUser(user:items[indexPath.row])
self.items.remove(indexPath.row)
```